# TypeScript: Get type of abstract method's implementation in real class

Tags: typescript

I have a map of functions, with different signatures

```
const allMyFunctions = {
  f1: () => Promise.resolve(1),
  f2: (a: number) => a
};
```

And an abstract class that does some stuff with these functions:

```
abstract class MyClass {
  protected abstract decorateMethod(...args: any[]): any;

  decorateAll() {
    return Object.keys(allMyFunctions)
      .reduce((acc, key) => {
        const f = allMyFunctions[key as keyof typeof allMyFunctions];

        acc[key as keyof typeof allMyFunctions] = this.decorateMethod(f);

        return acc;
      },{} as {[index in keyof typeof allMyFunctions]: ReturnType<MyClass['decorateMethod']>});
  }
}
```

So `decorateAll` creates a new map with the same keys, but each function goes through `decorateMethod`, which is abstract.

I can now instantiate 2 real classes as below:

```
class MyConstantClass extends MyClass {
  protected decorateMethod(f: AnyFunction) {
    return () => 2;
  }
}

class MyIdentityClass extends MyClass {
  protected decorateMethod<F extends AnyFunction>(f: F) {
    return f;
  }
}

const instance1 = new MyConstantClass();
const a = instance1.decorateAll().f1;

const instance2 = new MyIdentityClass();
const b = instance2.decorateAll().f2;
```

Unfortunately, the types of `a` and `b` are `any`, where in fact they should be `() => number` and `(a:number) => number`.

It seems that if I copy-paste the `decorateAll` implementation in children classes, and replace the last line casting with `ReturnType<MyIdentity['decorateMethod']>`, it works. But then there's duplicate logic, which I want to avoid by using the abstract class in the 1st place.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20AnyFunction%20%3D%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20any%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20allMyFunctions%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20f1%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Promise.resolve(1)%2C%0D%0A%20%20f2%3A%20(a%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20a%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aabstract%20class%20MyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20protected%20abstract%20decorateMethod(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20decorateAll()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Object.keys(allMyFunctions)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20.reduce((acc%2C%20key)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20f%20%3D%20allMyFunctions%5Bkey%20as%20keyof%20typeof%20allMyFunctions%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20acc%5Bkey%20as%20keyof%20typeof%20allMyFunctions%5D%20%3D%20this.decorateMethod(f)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20acc%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%7B%7D%20as%20%7B%5Bindex%20in%20keyof%20typeof%20allMyFunctions%5D%3A%20ReturnType%3CMyClass%5B'decorateMethod'%5D%3E%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyConstantClass%20extends%20MyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20protected%20decorateMethod(f%3A%20AnyFunction)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20()%20%3D%3E%202%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyIdentityClass%20extends%20MyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20protected%20decorateMethod%3CF%20extends%20AnyFunction%3E(f%3A%20F)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20f%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20instance1%20%3D%20new%20MyConstantClass()%3B%0D%0Aconst%20a%20%3D%20instance1.decorateAll().f1%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20instance2%20%3D%20new%20MyIdentityClass()%3B%0D%0Aconst%20b%20%3D%20instance2.decorateAll().f2%3B%0D%0A)

Edit: Add playground link

Comment: This whole construct will be difficult to type Since `decorateMethod` can just return `f`, `f` will be a union, so in the id case you will get `f2` as a union of all posible functions in `allMyFunctions` which is not really desirable .. you can get the type of the derived method using `ReturnType<this['decorateMethod']>` if you make `decorateMethod` public .. but the results don't seem very workable to me

Comment: "you can get the type of the derived method using ReturnType<this['decorateMethod']> if you make decorateMethod public" Can you explain this more in detail? E.g. a playground link

Comment: Explained in an answer, it would have been to long for a comment

Answer (score 1):

You can use polymorphic `this` to reference the current type of the class. This will let you write approximately what you want

```
const allMyFunctions = {
  f1: () => Promise.resolve(1),
  f2: (a: number) => a
};

type AnyFunction = typeof allMyFunctions[keyof typeof allMyFunctions];

abstract class MyClass {
  abstract decorateMethod(...args: any[]): any;

  decorateAll() {
      return Object.keys(allMyFunctions)
          .reduce((acc, key) => {
              const f = allMyFunctions[key as keyof typeof allMyFunctions];

              acc[key as keyof typeof allMyFunctions] = this.decorateMethod(f);

              return acc;
          }, {} as {
              [index in keyof typeof allMyFunctions]: ReturnType<this['decorateMethod']>
          });
  }
}

class MyConstantClass extends MyClass {
  decorateMethod(f: AnyFunction) {
      return () => 2;
  }
}

class MyIdentityClass extends MyClass {
  decorateMethod<F extends AnyFunction>(f: F) {
      return f;
  }
}


const instance1 = new MyConstantClass();
const a = instance1.decorateAll().f1; //  () => number

const instance2 = new MyIdentityClass();
const b = instance2.decorateAll().f2; //  This might not be what you want: (() => Promise<number>) | ((a: number) => number)
```

`MyConstantClass` works as expected, it returns for all functions `() => number` but `MyIdentityClass` returns a union of all function types in the object. This is because, the information that `decorateMethod` returns the same thing as the original is not captured in its type. `decorateMethod` takes a union and returns a union, and that mangles the types.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understood what you meant. I upvoted it, but unfortunately cannot accept it.

Comment: @amaurymartiny that is fine, that is why I originally posted as a comment . I'm afraid your current architecture is not fully type safe and can't be expressed in the TS type system though.

Comment: Thanks! "your current architecture is not fully type safe" do you mean it's intrinsically not type safe? For example, would it be possible to express it in haskell (which has higher kinded types)?

Answer (score 0):

Make your abstract class generic by including a `<T>` type, and make the result of `decorateMethod` be `T` (or `()=>T`) instead of `any`. Then the two concrete classes will extend e.g. `MyClass<number>` (or `MyClass<()=>number>`). This will solve at least one of your cases.

As for the second one where your `decorateMethod` takes `F` and returns `F`, it's not that easy, I think it's actually impossible to express that, as your `decorateMethod` is generic itself. I tried to do this [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20allMyFunctions%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20f1%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Promise.resolve(1)%2C%0D%0A%20%20f2%3A%20(a%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20a%0D%0A%7D%3B%20%0D%0A%0D%0Aabstract%20class%20MyClass%3CD%20extends%20(...args%3Aunknown%5B%5D)%3D%3Eunknown%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20protected%20decorateMethod%3A%20D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20decorateAll()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Object.keys(allMyFunctions)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20.reduce((acc%2C%20key)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20f%20%3D%20allMyFunctions%5Bkey%20as%20keyof%20typeof%20allMyFunctions%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20acc%5Bkey%20as%20keyof%20typeof%20allMyFunctions%5D%20%3D%20this.decorateMethod(f)%20as%20ReturnType%3CD%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20acc%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%7B%7D%20as%20%7B%5Bindex%20in%20keyof%20typeof%20allMyFunctions%5D%3A%20ReturnType%3CD%3E%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyConstantClass%20extends%20MyClass%3C(f%3Aany)%3D%3E(()%3D%3Enumber)%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20protected%20decorateMethod%3D(f%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20()%20%3D%3E%202%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyIdentityClass%20extends%20MyClass%3C%20%3CF%3E(f%3AF)%3D%3EF%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20protected%20decorateMethod%3D%3CF%3E(f%3A%20F)%20%3D%3E%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20f%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20instance1%20%3D%20new%20MyConstantClass()%3B%0D%0Aconst%20a%20%3D%20instance1.decorateAll().f1%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20instance2%20%3D%20new%20MyIdentityClass()%3B%0D%0Aconst%20b%20%3D%20instance2.decorateAll().f2%3B%0D%0A) but it doesn't work - TS removes the generics and returns `{}`.